# Remove a specific file name using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have not enough experience in writing rules in `.htaccess`.

My site url is like

`http://exampletest.com/detail.php?i=my-url`

I want to rewrite that url to

`http://exampletest.com/my-url`

**What I have tried so far:**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /detail\.php\?i=([^\s&][A-Za-z0-9-]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ detail %1? [R=302,L]
```

That makes me able to access my site using:

`http://exampletest.com/detail/my-url`

But I want to omit  `detail` from url as well.

Comment: What is `a` in `a=my-url`? Also, provide information about framework and stack you are using.

Comment: Sorry, but SO is _not_ a code writing service. We are here to help you fix your own code, not to do your work for you. I suggest you start reading a "getting started" guide like we all did.

Comment: This is in simple core php

Comment: I have tried almost like

Comment: http://exampletest.com/detail/my-url

Comment: but I want to hide detail

Comment: `exampletest.com/detail/my-url` works for you? Post your `.htaccess` content.

Comment: yes, It's work but I want to remove detail

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /detail\.php\?i=([^\s&][A-Za-z0-9-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ detail/%1? [R=302,L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redirect internally as well so your code should looks like this :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /detail\.php\?i=([^\s&][A-Za-z0-9-]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^  %1? [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$    /detail.php?i=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /detail\.php\?i=([^\s&][A-Za-z0-9-]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: url has been changed.but a new issue generated. 404 - File Not Found

Comment: So, you are not getting the page against new url?